# When I try to DIV I get "Divide by zero" But its not zero

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

When I try to divide a number by two I get "Divide by zero" error.

Current status:

[image: Current registers status]

```
AX = 0009
```

I have this line

```
Two DW 2
```

And when I am trying to do

```
DIV Two
```

I get this error:

[image: Error divide by zero]

What is the problem?

Comment: Divide by zero isn't the only thing that can raise a `#DE` exception.

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear `dx` before dividing.  Recall, `div` divides `DX:AX` by the operand, not just `DX`.  If you do not clear `DX`, the resulting quotient does not fit into a 16 bit word, causing the CPU to generate an exception.  This is the same exception you get for a division by zero and the debugger doesn't try to tell the two error sources apart.